# sh/bash command substitution freezes script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

There is simple one-line script:

```
myvar=`nano`
```

If I run this with bash or sh it freezes current terminal session and editor will not be shown. I tried other interactive programs and different operating systems (Ubuntu, FreeBSD), results are always the same. I think it's because those programs are ignoring signals, but I don't understand why they can't start in such a way.

I need this method because I want to release the function that captures text input from user and return it to caller. For example:

```
function read_text()
{
   local tempfile=`mktemp`
   nano $tempfile
   cat $tempfile
   rm $tempfile
}

echo "Press ENTER to input your comment." 
read # ENTER
comment=`read_text`
```

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to tripleee for directing me to the reason of this problem. I found simple solution. It is to redirect problem to current terminal line.

There is simple one-line script:

```
myvar=`nano > $(tty)`
```

Full example:

```
read_text()
{
   local tempfile=`mktemp`
   nano $tempfile > `tty`
   cat $tempfile
   rm $tempfile
}
comment=`read_text`
echo $comment
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the contents of `$tempfile`? If it is empty, the `cat` command will hang your execution.

Comment: No, `cat` isn't the reason, because Ctrl+D should work if command blocks script to read STDIN. Of course, I've tried to comment `cat`. So that's why I've posted one-line test case.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't use the `function` keyword -- it has no benefit over the POSIX standard syntax but makes your script needlessly incompatible. Just write `read_text() {` with no `function` before it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run interactive commands inside backircks, because the backticks will prevent interactive input and output between the program and your terminal.

A reasonable refactoring of your problem would be to handle the temp file in the caller, and do away with the function; or at least, reduce the scope of the function.

```
local tempfile=$(mktemp)
${VISUAL-nano} "$tempfile"
comment=$(cat "$tempfile")
rm "$tempfile"
```

Notice also how this code uses `$VISUAL` and falls back to `nano` only if this standard variable is unset.

For most real-world scenarios, if the input task is significant enough to warrant the use of an external editor, you will probably be better off passing around the temporary file (use a `trap` to remove it at the very end of the script) instead of grabbing its contents into a shell variable.

```
# At the beginning of your script
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -t yourscript.XXXXXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' 0
trap 'exit 127' 1 2 3 5 15

:

echo '# Enter your comment here' >"$tmpdir"/comment
${VISUAL-nano} "$tmpdir"/comment
```

As you can see, this turns out simple enough that you don't really need to encapsulate it into a separate function.

Comment: Ok, thank you, now I understand what happens. The program is running, but it can't draw anything, because its STDOUT assigned to the bash, not the terminal. But how to make this action as a subprogram not just part of code itself?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure I know what more needs to be explained... See additional edit just now.

Comment: I meant I need to use it as a function, so I can call it from anywhere in my program. Thank you for the help, I've posted solution in the description update.